# Creating bitmap from xml layouts, off the ui thread

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps, bitmap

I'm trying to create multiple bitmaps, one for each map marker.
Since it happens on the ui thread, the ui freezes for a moment..

Is there a way to create a bitmap using a layout xml on a background/worker thread?
I know that It's not recommended, but I'm not sure how to tackle this issue.

If there's a way to create a designed bitmap not using my current method, 
i'll be glad to hear..

Thanks

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...
    mMarkerContainer = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(
            getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.map_text_marker, null);

    mMarkerNameTv = (TextView) mMarkerContainer
            .findViewById(R.id.map_marker_name);
    ...

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

public Bitmap createMarkerBitmap(int markerRes, String markerName) {
    mMarkerNameTv.setText(markerName);
    mMarkerContainer.setBackground(mBitmapDrawables.get(markerRes));

    int measureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
            View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    mMarkerContainer.measure(measureSpec, measureSpec);

    int measuredWidth = mMarkerContainer.getMeasuredWidth();
    int measuredHeight = mMarkerContainer.getMeasuredHeight();

    mMarkerContainer.layout(0, 0, measuredWidth, measuredHeight);

    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(measuredWidth,
            measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    resultBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
    mMarkerContainer.draw(canvas);

    return resultBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a bitmap using a layout xml on a background/worker thread?

AFAIK, working with widgets on a background thread is not a problem, so long as they are not connected to any window (e.g., they are not part of an activity or dialog). Inflating a layout might be a problem -- I seem to recall running into that with instrumentation tests, which do not run on the main application thread. But you're welcome to try putting your `inflate()` call and all of the `createMarkerBitmap()` logic into a background thread.

However:

- Creating and populating widgets normally does not take much time. You may be better served using Traceview to determine why yours is taking so long.
- If the issue isn't that an individual bitmap is slow, but that you are creating two tons of bitmaps, that will be a problem regardless of how you do it. Just because the work is done on a background thread does not make it "free" from a CPU standpoint, plus there are memory pressures to consider.

> If there's a way to create a designed bitmap not using my current method, i'll be glad to hear.

You could draw directly to the `Canvas` using the methods available on `Canvas`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can use an extension of `AsyncTask`, like this:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
 protected Long doInBackground(Integer... bitmapID) {
     return loadYourBitmap(bitmapID[0]);   //<-happens in background
 }
 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap yourBitmap) {
     setSomethingTo(yourBitmap);  //<- happens in foreground when doInBackground is done
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to this problem is to cache the bitmaps. When you want to display multiple markers as bitmaps. Simple `[LruCache][1]` - based in-memory cache would work just fine. The only thing that is needed to be taken care of is how much memory you are using for caching. Have a look at this official Google docs to know more about [caching in bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html).

You can cache BitmapDescriptor for every unique bitmap you have. This way you can get some extra performance by avoiding making calls to BitmapDescriptorFactory every time you need to create a marker.

Here is the sample code:

```
LruCache<String, BitmapDescriptor> cache;

private void initCache()
{
    //Use 1/8 of available memory
    cache = new LruCache<String, BitmapDescriptor>((int)(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 8));
}

private void addMarker(LatLng position, String assetPath)
{
    MarkerOptions opts = new MarkerOptions();
    opts.icon(getBitmapDescriptor(assetPath));
    opts.position(position);
    mMap.addMarker(opts);
}

private BitmapDescriptor getBitmapDescriptor(String path) {
    BitmapDescriptor result = cache.get(path);
    if (result == null) {
        result = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset(path);
        cache.put(path, result);
    }

    return result;
}
```